# Understanding autoresizing property and masks

Tags: ios, objective-c, interface-builder

In terms of the images, to which image does the value `UIViewAutoresizingNone` correspond to when set on a view?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You are right the image you shown is equivalent to `UIViewAutoresizingNone`.

The Autosizing, you can see from ***Interface Builder*** is something like,

[image]

While ***programmatically*** these struts behave '*reversed*' of above image like,

[image]

### Here are some example for AutoSizingMask - Programmatically vs XIB.

- (`UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight`) is equivalent to

[image]

- (`UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin |UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin`) is equivalent to

[image]

- `UIViewAutoresizingNone` is equivalent to

[image]

- (`UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin`) is equivalent to

[image]

- (`UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin`) is equivalent to

[image]

- (`UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight`) is equivalent to

[image]

- (`UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight`) is equivalent to

[image]

- (`UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth`) is equivalent to

[image]

- (`UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin`)

[image]

Comment: The top image you show is equivalent to `UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin  | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin`. The bottom image is equivalent to `UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight`.

Answer (score 0):

Do this for the `UIViewAutoresizingNone`:
[image]

And for the future reference just use the side example which shows how your Autosizing will behave:

[image]

Comment: This is the default but it is equivalent to `UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the image in your question means `UIViewAutoresizingNone`. The bars on the outside being set mean 'non-flexible' but the arrows on the inside being set means `flexible`.

Note that if you try to set `UIViewAutoresizingNone` and then resize the superview it won't be respected as something has to change.

Comment: there are varying responses. See for example response by @Bhargavi. But I think the correct one is the one I uploaded in my question, the one that corresponds to UIViewAutoresizingNone. (although one might expect correct is one from Bhargavi).

Comment: The one from @Bhargavi makes logical sense but it actually wrong as I describe. I do agree with the other answers that you should look at the animated image.

Comment: Yes, I agree with you I think. It's a bit strange that it is like this (inversed) but it is correct what we are talking about

Comment: Yes and it will give you the exact idea how it will behave not for only this but also other autosizing